# getting $('button').attr("value") on console return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm trying to build a calculator but I have yet a problem at begin.
I retrieve undefined on `attr('value')` of buttons.

Here is the code

```
<button value="8" class="">8</button>

var input = '';
$("button").click(function(){
   input = $("this").attr("value");
   console.log(input);  
});
```

I can't figure out why....

Comment: `$("this")` ==>  `$(this)` **No Quotes**

Comment: And I'll suggest to use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$("this")` to `$(this)` (`this` shouldn't be a string) and it should work:

```js
var input = '';
$("button").on('click', function(){
   input = $(this).attr("value");
   console.log(input);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="8" class="asdas">8</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**$(this)** is different from **$("this")**.

**$("this")** will take it as a `$("element")` which is element selector . where it  Selects all elements with the given tag name. in your case it will find the element as `this` . which is not available in DOM .

```js
var input = '';
$("button").click(function(){
input = $(this).attr("value");
console.log(input);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="8" class="">8</button>
```

**FYI**: i suggest you to use `.val()` instead of `.attr()` because 
attr(...) is only getting the objects value at the start (when the html is created). val() is getting the object's property value which can change many times.

Answer (score 0):

Use plain javascript `this.value`

```js
var input = '';
$("button").on('click', function(){
   input = this.value;
   console.log(input);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="8" class="asdas">8</button>
```